Code in Jupyter Notebook doesn't give same results in Visual Studio Code
My code returns the entire HTML of the site when I use Jupyter Notebook:
heads = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

for pag in range(1,5):
    url = f"https://www.imovelweb.com.br/apartamentos-venda-porto-alegre-rs.html"
    response = requests.get(url,headers=heads)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')

When I run the same code in Visual Studio Code it returns:
1ε�&amp;�cг5/��W♠�yu�0;r��⌂�~���f�������|����Ʋx�g�S (��yN�|?��, �Y������l�pE�˞��]l↓E�b�%^5�@�↨3�M���→Ҝ���A►♦��¶�XSҒ�    ���5�☼�A►\�♠�☻...

I noticed that when changing/deleting 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', it ends up executing normally, but with data protection for scrap. I would like some explanation as to why such a thing happens.


'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'

This header tells the server that the client (your script) can handle compressed content. The server then sends the compressed response using one of the specified methods (gzip, deflate, or br).
You could try to change soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser') to soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser'). This will allow you to handle compressed content, which can make your requests faster and use less bandwidth.
